# What type of antenna is this?

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory

I have very little knowledge about antennas (I just read about simple dipoles and monopoles recently) and I need to buy a directional antenna for my wireless device. I have found a cheap antenna (I know cheap eBay antennas are not what the sellers claim) and I want to know more about the antenna before buying it. The seller listed that it has an 8dbi gain, <2 VSWR and they didn't provide the radiation pattern. I have an image of the antenna elements, can you please tell me the type of the antenna? Then, I can read some more about this specific type.

Inside, it is formed by two plates. The driven element is a 40x50mm plate. The reflector is larger, curved, and grounded. A black plastic is there between the plates but there is a metal bolt in the center causing electrical contact between the plates.

Edit: Is the metal bolt okay in this design? It is sorting the patch and the ground.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please forgive me if this is a very common antenna. As I have said, I am very new to this.

Comment: Yes, it is okay. At the center point is ground on both plates/patches.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Planar or Patch Antenna.
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/rf-and-microwave/9781118349571/c07_level1_5.xhtml

Comment: Thank you for the introduction about patch antennas. I will create a trial account and read the full text. But just a follow up question, is the metal bolt okay? It is sorting the patch and the ground plane.

Comment: Thanks Joerg for the helpful tip here and welcome to the site! I should point out that we try to encourage answers to include a summary of the relevant parts of linked content especially (but not only) when they require a subscription to access. A lot of times just knowing what something is called is half the battle, though, so this is well on its way to being a helpful answer already!